# Azure Analytics: Difference Between Log vs standard based metrics

Tags: azure, azure-analytics

We are using AppService on Azure which has application insights enabled. While looking at CPU usage we found that while log based metrics that average CPU is 40-80% while standard based metrics is showing CPU usage for same period and resource to be 150-300%.

Can someone explain why there is so much difference? and how come CPU usage go till 300% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU can be counted in cores (max value = #NumCores * 100) or normalized (average across all cores). For instance, if your app runs on 4 core virtual machine, then 75% overall CPU utilization will map to 300% CPU-core utilization.

I guess in your case one metric is normalized and another isn't.